# Do coffee lagers exist?

Tags: lager

I've had coffee stouts a number of different places. This seems to be a fairly common additive at American microbreweries. However, it seems like they are always adding coffee to stouts. I was wondering if any breweries are adding it to a lighter beer like a lager where the coffee flavor could more fully dominate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes Coffee Lagers exist.

Some call them [Coffee Beer](https://www.craftbeer.com/styles/coffee-beer) as a generic name for all styles of Coffee Beer.

> As the name suggests, **this can be either a lager or ale with coffee added to boost flavor.** While stouts and porters are popular base styles for coffee beer, many craft breweries are experimenting with other styles, like cream ales and India pale ales. Brewers may steep the beans in either water or beer to impart java flavor without adding acidity. Barrel-aged or wood-influenced versions may show signs of oxidation, including sherry notes and other advanced flavors.

Here is one example of a Cold Brew Coffee Lager: [Saranac](https://www.saranac.com/beer/cold-brew/).

Comment: again I stand amazed at what you know.

Comment: Try a Stone Mocha IPA if you can get one.

Comment: @Alaskaman Go ahead and make an answer of your nice comment.